Using javascript to call a page anchor using a content in a variable array
JS newbie here...
I'm using a script inside Wordpress to reveal page modules when a coverflow-style carousel panel is clicked. This uses CSS classes to show and hide the various panels on the page.
It works fine, but if you click a panel that's not front and center, the right module is revealed, but the carousel stays still.
I can call the correct carousel panel using page anchors attached to the panels. This works fine as hard-coded html links, But, I need to call this anchor from the JS.
The code uses a variable array for each of the possible states, e.g. when mtc_button_1 is clicked, hide mtc_element_2, _3, _4, _5, and show mtc_element_1.
So, is there a way of adding an additional field to the array to call the page anchor???
I'm guessing its something along the lines of using window.location.href, but I@m struggling to get the syntax right.
Thanks in advance!
This is the code with my thoughts as comments:
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    var buttons = {
    '.mtc_button_1': {
        'toggle': '', 
        'hide'  : '.mtc_element_2,.mtc_element_3, .mtc_element_4, .mtc_element_5', 
        'show'  : '.mtc_element_1',
        //'panel' : '#panel1'

    },
    '.mtc_button_2': {
        'toggle': '', 
        'hide'  : '.mtc_element_1,.mtc_element_3, .mtc_element_4, .mtc_element_5', 
        'show'  : '.mtc_element_2',
        //'panel' : '#panel2'


    },
    '.mtc_button_3': {
        'toggle': '', 
        'hide'  : '.mtc_element_1,.mtc_element_2, .mtc_element_4, .mtc_element_5', 
        'show'  : '.mtc_element_3',
        //'panel' : '#panel3'
    },
    '.mtc_button_4': {
        'toggle': '', 
        'hide'  : '.mtc_element_1,.mtc_element_2, .mtc_element_3, .mtc_element_5', 
        'show'  : '.mtc_element_4',
        //'panel' : '#panel4'

    }
        
};
    $.each(buttons, function(button, elements) { //assume I need ,panel_choice here
        $(button).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(elements.toggle).slideToggle();
            $(elements.hide).fadeOut( 200 );
            $(elements.show).delay( 200 ).fadeIn( 200 );
            $(button).toggleClass('mtc_button_opened mtc_button_closed');
            //$(panel_choice.window.location.href) = panel;
        });
    });
});
</script>


You need to correct your code as follows:
Firstly, uncomment the panel property to identify each object.
Secondly, on the button click check if the elements.panel exists, and if so set window.location.href the value of elements.panel.
Refer the below code :


jQuery(function($){
    var buttons = {
        '.mtc_button_1': {
            'toggle': '', 
            'hide'  : '.mtc_element_2,.mtc_element_3, .mtc_element_4, .mtc_element_5', 
            'show'  : '.mtc_element_1',
            'panel' : '#panel1'
        },
        '.mtc_button_2': {
            'toggle': '', 
            'hide'  : '.mtc_element_1,.mtc_element_3, .mtc_element_4, .mtc_element_5', 
            'show'  : '.mtc_element_2',
            'panel' : '#panel2'
        },
        '.mtc_button_3': {
            'toggle': '', 
            'hide'  : '.mtc_element_1,.mtc_element_2, .mtc_element_4, .mtc_element_5', 
            'show'  : '.mtc_element_3',
            'panel' : '#panel3'
        },
        '.mtc_button_4': {
            'toggle': '', 
            'hide'  : '.mtc_element_1,.mtc_element_2, .mtc_element_3, .mtc_element_5', 
            'show'  : '.mtc_element_4',
            'panel' : '#panel4'
        }
    };

    $.each(buttons, function(button, elements) {
        $(button).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(elements.toggle).slideToggle();
            $(elements.hide).fadeOut(200);
            $(elements.show).delay(200).fadeIn(200);
            $(button).toggleClass('mtc_button_opened mtc_button_closed');
            if(elements.panel) {
                window.location.href = elements.panel; // set window.location href to elements.panel
            }
        });
    });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



